# Replace submit button with font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to replace submit button with font awesome icon, I already tried it myself and the icon won't show up on the button. 
Here is what I have done so far :

```
<form action="{{route('destroycourse', $course->id)}}" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
   <li><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
          <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this course ?');" style="border: 0; background: none;">
            <i class="fa fa-delete"></i>
          </button>
       </a>
   </li>
</form>
```

The button works just fine only the icon `<i class="fa fa-delete"></i>` won't show up and it's just showing a blank button. Thanks for the help!

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: place that class to `button`, not `i` element. you doesn't provide css, too.

Comment: @nelek the `i` element is fine to have the `fa` class. Preston, did you include the font awesome css? https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Comment: @disinfor yeap, my bad :-/

Comment: It's working now, I just misspelled the icon "fa fa-delete" instead of "fa fa-trash-o" my bad @nelek

Comment: It's working now, I just misspelled the icon "fa fa-delete" instead of "fa fa-trash-o" my bad @disinfor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I couldn't find `fa-delete`. I have used `fa-trash` to display trash icon.
You just need to include the font-awesome css in your code and correct class name.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form action="{{route('destroycourse', $course->id)}}" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
   <li><a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
          <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this course ?');" style="border: 0; background: none;">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>

       </a>
   </li>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong class of fontawesome

change class of `fa fa-delete` to `fa fa-trash`.

Working fiddle

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ocs69ss5/16/)**

```css
button {
  background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Actually, `fa fa-delete`should work since it's an alias for `fa fa-trash`.So probably something with his/hers imports that is not working.

Comment: May be but right now fontawesome does't have any delete class

Comment: Ah, you're correct. I just seached `delete` on the site, but that's just the search alias... Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such a class for icon that you are using is **fa-delete**.use the classes which are present. 
for your reference, use these links.
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_text.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_webapp.asp

**else use class "fa-trash-o" for delete icon**